# Cyclic recursion call in neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to input few graph nodes in neo4j db using spring-data-neo4j.

Nodes are having the following relationship.

`Project -> Cluster -> Entity -> Methods` and **Entity** node has relationship with its ownn, making it bidirectinoal relationship.

Entity class is defined as follows.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator =  ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "id")
@NodeEntity
public class Entity {
        public int id;
        public String type;
        public String name;
        public String entityId;
        Public String projectId;
        @Relationship(type = "CONNECTS_TO", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
        private Set<Entity> entityIdr;

    }
```

Below error is thrown while trying to insert Cluster and Entity nodes, what could be possible resolution to avoid following ?

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:  Infinite
> recursion (StackOverflowError)    (through reference chain:

Comment: Is thi `private Set<Entity> entityIdr;` not causing this cyclic recursion?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you try to serialize the data and expose it on the web layer or similar, right?
The jackson serialization needs to get more informations on how to break the cycles the Java data model describes.
So either you ignore a property with `@JsonIgnore` like

```
@JsonIgnore
@Relationship(type = "CONNECTS_TO", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<Entity> entityIdr;
```

, but that seems at least for the first level like a loss of information,
or

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("entityIdr")
@Relationship(type = "CONNECTS_TO", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<Entity> entityIdr;
```

We wrote this up in the documentation for Neo4j-OGM: https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#_a_note_on_json_serialization